# Removing punctuation in a text file in java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to read a text file called "text.txt" and then remove the punctuation in that file however I need some help. The first code below is the file reading portion, I'm trying to just remove the punctuation. The second code is me trying to remove it but it didn't work. Help??

```
public class file {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   try {
      File file = new File("text.txt");
      Scanner myReader = new Scanner(file);
      while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
         String data = myReader.nextLine();
         System.out.println(data);
      }
   }
   }
}
```

```
String line;
String processedLine="";
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
   processedLine = line.replaceAll("!~`@#$%^&*()-_=+'><:;?","");
}
```

I tried to hardcode all the punctuation away but it didn’t work.

Comment: what about `line.replaceAll("\\{Punct}, "");` ?

Comment: What happens after you process each line? Are you writing it to a different file, or doing something else with it? Otherwise, changes in `processedLine` will be lost

Comment: I wonder how the two code snippets correlate - And "it didn't work" is kind of useless, please be more specific, what exactly is happening? Also better to include a [mre] in the question

Comment: Is there a reason you are reading the file line by line? It would be more efficient to read the entire file and call your replaceAll call just once

Answer (score 0):

I posted a comment earlier with a typo in it, so I thought I'd correct it with working code below:

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class PunctuationFilter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Files.lines(Paths.get(args[0]))
                    .map(s -> s.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", ""))
                    .forEach(System.out::println);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```